# Trying to update jquery variables using mysql and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to make a Charity counter using jquery, php and mysql.
I am trying to grab new values from mysql using php every 5 seconds without updating the page using 'window.setInterval()', but my problem is that it isnt grabbing new values but it keeps using the values it got at the start. so here' s the code, i hope some is able to help :).

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var needed = <?php echo neededGetFirst(); ?>;
    var got = <?php echo gotGetFirst(); ?>;
    console.log('needed: ' + needed);
    console.log('got: ' + got);
    var gaugeHeight = 223;
    var gaugeBottom = 318;
    var percent = (100 / needed) * got;
    var heightOffset = (gaugeHeight / 100) * percent;
    var bottomOffset = gaugeBottom - (gaugeHeight - heightOffset);

    $('#gauge').animate({
         height: heightOffset + 'px',
         bottom: bottomOffset + 'px'
    }, 1000);

    for (var i = 2, limit = 7; i < limit; i++) {
         var value = (needed / 5) * (i - 1);
         $('#stamp' + i).text(value);
    };
}, 5000);
```

**EDIT**

Is it possible to return the value from a file with some type of `GET/RUN`? by putting the php/mysql database functions in an file and use a `return` for the values.'

**EDIT 2**

The php code used in the file:

```
<?php
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=thermometer', 'root', ''); 
  $sql = 'SELECT `got`.`value` AS got, `needed`.`value` AS needed FROM `needed`, `got`'; 
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = json_encode($result );
  echo($json);
?>
```

Comment: You want to access a server side value (Votes got) in the window.setInterval, you need to use AJAX for this. Your current code will ofcourse use the values it got at the beginning, because you are echoing the "got" value on page load, there is no piece of code that is refreshing that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned, to update the page with new values every however many seconds, you will need some kind of interaction with the server, probably via AJAX.

Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
function getNewValues(){
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'submit.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false
  });
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  getNewValues()
  .success(function(data) {
    var needed = data["needed"],
        got = data["got"];

    var gaugeHeight = 223;
    var gaugeBottom = 318;
    var percent = (100 / needed) * got;
    var heightOffset = (gaugeHeight / 100) * percent;
    var bottomOffset = gaugeBottom - (gaugeHeight - heightOffset);

    $('#gauge').animate({
      height: heightOffset + 'px',
      bottom: bottomOffset + 'px'
    }, 1000);

    for (var i = 2, limit = 7; i < limit; i++) {
      var value = (needed / 5) * (i - 1);
      $('#stamp' + i).text(value);
    };
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("An error ocurred");
  });
}, 500);
```

Now, every five seconds a request will fire to the server and retrieve the latest values.

You will have to adjust your PHP script to return some simple JSON:

```
{
    "needed": needed_value,
    "got": got_value
}
```

Maybe something like:

```
<?php
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db_name', 'user', 'pass'); 
  $sql = 'SELECT needed, got FROM table'; 
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetch();
  $json = json_encode($result );
  echo($json);
?>
```

Although this isn't tested, it should hopefully point you on the right path.

Comment: Is it possible to use a left join on this? if so, could you write an example? becouse the server querry works but i have to grab data from 2 different tables

Comment: You must be getting the data anyway, as you are outputting it on the page. Just use what you have.

Comment: Im getting the error: `TypeError: got is undefined`, and the echo from the file: `[{"got":"1235.00","needed":"4350"}]`

Comment: Change your code to: `var newValues = getNewValues(); console.log(newValues);` What does that output?

Comment: newValues gives back `undefined`, and the data that being returned in the function: `Array [ Object ]`.

Comment: Would help to see your PHP. Don't know if that is possible here. We can't move this to chat, as you don't have enough rep.

Comment: I have put the php in an edit, thats all the php code i use atm

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. `var newValues = getNewValues(), needed = newValues[needed], got = newValues[got];` The property names should be in quotes: `var newValues = getNewValues(), needed = newValues["needed"], got = newValues["got"];` or using the dot notation: `var newValues = getNewValues(), needed = newValues.needed, got = newValues.got;`

Comment: Im still getting the error `TypeError: newValues is undefined` :p, do you alse have a solution for that?

Comment: I just tested this. The problem was me not taking into account the asynchronous nature of AJAX requests. I updated the JS to take this into account and I also updated the PHP to fetch only one record (which is what you seem to have been doing). This works for me. Would be great to find out if it works for you. If you still have questions, feel free to hit me up via Twitter (see my profile page), as we are unable to move this to chat.